# session management windows azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage

How does azure manage asp.net style session management.
for eg in general asp.net applications when multiple users are hitting the applcations.
username is stored in session which is available to each user.
How can this be managed with windows azure for sites on multiple instances with form authentication.
App fabric caching is alternative but then when multiple users hit the site then how is cache key shared?

Comment: Why do you care how the data will be stored in SQL or ATS as long as it works?  Are you unable to store Session data?

Comment: as i asked in cirrus suggestions comment. when i have two users with say username abc and xyz and i want to store username under key "username" how does table storage handles it? and gives out values to specific user? just want to know for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that different to session management on multiple instances outside Azure. You can't use in-memory session state obviously, but other than that, you've plenty of options. You could use the SQL store provider for instance, or use one for Azure tables.

Better still, try and engineer out the use of session state altogether wherever possible.

Comment: if i have two users logging in on azure site,how will the data be stored in azure cache or table storage if i want to store say their respective usernames as session data.

Comment: Azure won't do anything special automatically with session state for your web app. You'll need to decide how you want to manage that. The SQL Provider is a good place to start as it's well documented, but you'll need to hook into SQLAzure. Ideally, pick an Azure implementation instead, there are plenty: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=azure%20table%20session%20state%20provider Just think of Azure Web  Roles like you do web servers elsewhere. The session state problem is the same. Set Web.config so that your session state persists off the machine. You can't rely on in-memory state either way.